# Composer does not see dataflow job succeeded

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-composer

I am using Gcloud Composer to launch Dataflow jobs.

My DAG consist of two Dataflow jobs that should be run one after the other.

```
import datetime

from airflow.contrib.operators.dataflow_operator import DataflowTemplateOperator
from airflow import models


default_dag_args = {

    'start_date': datetime.datetime(2019, 10, 23),
    'dataflow_default_options': {
               'project': 'myproject',
               'region': 'europe-west1',
               'zone': 'europe-west1-c',
               'tempLocation': 'gs://somebucket/',
               }
}

with models.DAG(
        'some_name',
        schedule_interval=datetime.timedelta(days=1),
        default_args=default_dag_args) as dag:

    parameters = {'params': "param1"}

    t1 = DataflowTemplateOperator(
        task_id='dataflow_example_01',
        template='gs://path/to/template/template_001',
        parameters=parameters,
        dag=dag)

    parameters2 = {'params':"param2"}

    t2 = DataflowTemplateOperator(
        task_id='dataflow_example_02',
        template='gs://path/to/templates/template_002',
        parameters=parameters2,
        dag=dag
    )

    t1 >> t2
```

When I check in dataflow the job has succeeded, all the files it is supposed to make are created, but it appears it ran in US region, the cloud composer environment is in Europe west.

In airflow  I can see that the first job is still running so the second one is not launched

[image]

What should I add to the DAG to make it succeed? How do I run in Europe?

Any advice or solution on how to proceed would be most appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had to solve this issue in the past. In Airflow [1.10.2](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/1.10.2/airflow/contrib/hooks/gcp_dataflow_hook.py#L285) (or lower) the code calls to the `service.projects().templates().launch()` endpoint. This was fixed in [1.10.3](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/1.10.3/airflow/contrib/hooks/gcp_dataflow_hook.py#L283) where the regional one is used instead: `service.projects().locations().templates().launch()`.

As of October 2019, the latest Airflow version available for Composer environments is 1.10.2. If you need a solution immediately, the fix can be back-ported into Composer.

For this we can override the `DataflowTemplateOperator` for our own version called `RegionalDataflowTemplateOperator`:

```py
class RegionalDataflowTemplateOperator(DataflowTemplateOperator):
  def execute(self, context):
    hook = RegionalDataFlowHook(gcp_conn_id=self.gcp_conn_id,
                        delegate_to=self.delegate_to,
                        poll_sleep=self.poll_sleep)

    hook.start_template_dataflow(self.task_id, self.dataflow_default_options,
                                 self.parameters, self.template)
```

This will now make use of the modified `RegionalDataFlowHook` which overrides the `start_template_dataflow` method of the `DataFlowHook` operator to call the correct endpoint:

```py
class RegionalDataFlowHook(DataFlowHook):
  def _start_template_dataflow(self, name, variables, parameters,
                               dataflow_template):
      ...
      request = service.projects().locations().templates().launch(
          projectId=variables['project'],
          location=variables['region'],
          gcsPath=dataflow_template,
          body=body
      )
      ...
      return response
```

Then, we can create a task using our new operator and a Google-provided template (for testing purposes):

```py
task = RegionalDataflowTemplateOperator(
    task_id=JOB_NAME,
    template=TEMPLATE_PATH,
    parameters={
        'inputFile': 'gs://dataflow-samples/shakespeare/kinglear.txt',
        'output': 'gs://{}/europe/output'.format(BUCKET)
    },
    dag=dag,
)
```

Full working DAG [here](https://github.com/gxercavins/gcp-snippets/blob/master/composer/regional-df-template/df-europe-west1.py). For a cleaner version, the operator can be moved into a separate module.

Comment: thanks this works,
but the request in the regionaldataflowhool should be:

        request = service.projects().locations().templates().launch(
          projectId=PROJECT,
          location=REGION,
          gcsPath=dataflow_template,
          body=body
        )

in my opinion